# Ansible execute remote ssh task

Tags: ansible

I have tried connecting to a remote "custom" Linux vm, and copied my ssh public ssh it, yet, I'm able to get Ansible to ping / connect it, as I keep getting remote host unreachable. "*I think its because its running custom version of linux and ssh auth might be behaving differently*"

The following remote ssh command works

```
 # ssh -t user@server_ip "show vd"
 password: mypassword
```

I'm trying to convert this above command to an Ansible playbook

```
---
- hosts: server_ip
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
    - name: check devise status
      shell: ssh -i server_ip "show vd"
      register: output

    - expect:
      command: sh "{{ output.stdout }}"
      responses:
        (?i)password: user
```

I'm unable to get it to work, and I'm not sure if this is the write way of doing it, your input is highly appreciated it.

Comment: how/where are you running that playbook from ? I think your logic might be a bit wrong - please have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/serialdoom/87d7ebf486c71b3cd74f) gist

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have ssh connection problems you should add the -vvvv parameter to your ansible-playbook command line. That way it will give detailed information about the ssh connection and errors.